# Can I do an animated wordcloud in R with {wordcloud} or {wordcloud2}?

Tags: r, word-cloud

I managed to make one wordcloud with `ggwordcloud` but the results is not pretty and not what I want for the number of frames, etc

```r
library(tidyverse); library(magrittr); library(ggwordcloud); library(gganimate)

df_all <- structure(list(age = c(16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L), definition = c("mommy*", "daddy*", "ball", "uh oh", "bye", "dog", "hi", "no", "woof woof", "yum yum", "moo", "shoe", "baby", "baa baa", "grrr", "banana", "book", "duck", "meow", "hello", "eye", "car", "nose", "bird", "hot", "balloon", "ouch", "kitty", "vroom", "ear", "cookie", "juice", "night night", "grandma*", "cheese", "bath", "apple", "hat", "thank you", "quack quack", "yes", "cat", "please", "bubbles", "milk", "water (not beverage)", "water (beverage)", "grandpa*", "bear", "cracker", "shh/shush/hush", "diaper", "hair", "go", "fish (animal)", "truck", "child's own name", "eat", "mine", "cup", "up", "choo choo", "spoon", "all gone", "bus", "owie/boo boo", "outside", "door", "down", "airplane", "tree", "cow", "bed", "peekaboo", "blanket", "hand", "horse", "mouth", "flower", "pig", "train", "chair", "light", "tummy", "arm", "toothbrush", "TV", "sock", "open", "fork", "foot", "bottle", "ice cream", "big", "monkey", "boat", "home", "kiss", "more", "pizza", "telephone", "rain", "pants", "head", "cake", "finger", "shirt", "bread", "potty", "belly button", "keys", "cold", "toy (object)", "bunny", "drink (action)", "bee", "on", "bicycle", "bug", "moon", "hug", "play", "candy", "help", "orange (food)", "drink (beverage)", "love", "paper", "toe", "cereal", "dirty", "grapes", "bowl", "elephant", "leg", "frog", "go potty", "jump", "nap", "pillow"), frequency = c(1, 0.991021324354658, 0.822671156004489, 0.820426487093154, 0.777777777777778, 0.729517396184063, 0.698092031425365, 0.691358024691358, 0.640852974186307, 0.598204264870932, 1, 0.988023952095808, 0.976047904191617, 0.934131736526946, 0.92814371257485, 0.910179640718563, 0.856287425149701, 0.844311377245509, 0.796407185628742, 0.790419161676647, 1, 0.986394557823129, 0.976190476190476, 0.942176870748299, 0.91156462585034, 0.904761904761905, 0.904761904761905, 0.894557823129252, 0.894557823129252, 0.884353741496599, 1, 0.97787610619469, 0.97787610619469, 0.946902654867257, 0.933628318584071, 0.915929203539823, 0.907079646017699, 0.902654867256637, 0.898230088495575, 0.893805309734513, 1, 0.948979591836735, 0.943877551020408, 0.938775510204082, 0.933673469387755, 0.88265306122449, 0.877551020408163, 0.846938775510204, 0.841836734693878, 0.831632653061224, 1, 0.985915492957746, 0.957746478873239, 0.950704225352113, 0.929577464788732, 0.922535211267606, 0.915492957746479, 0.915492957746479, 0.915492957746479, 0.908450704225352, 1, 0.986577181208054, 0.986577181208054, 0.966442953020134, 0.966442953020134, 0.959731543624161, 0.953020134228188, 0.946308724832215, 0.946308724832215, 0.939597315436242, 1, 0.995192307692308, 0.990384615384615, 0.980769230769231, 0.975961538461538, 0.966346153846154, 0.947115384615385, 0.942307692307692, 0.9375, 0.9375, 1, 0.980477223427332, 0.973969631236443, 0.924078091106291, 0.915401301518438, 0.913232104121475, 0.913232104121475, 0.908893709327549, 0.900216919739696, 0.89587852494577, 1, 0.993630573248408, 0.987261146496815, 0.980891719745223, 0.980891719745223, 0.97452229299363, 0.97452229299363, 0.97452229299363, 0.97452229299363, 0.97452229299363, 1, 0.994117647058824, 0.982352941176471, 0.970588235294118, 0.964705882352941, 0.964705882352941, 0.964705882352941, 0.958823529411765, 0.958823529411765, 0.952941176470588, 1, 0.997350993377483, 0.990728476821192, 0.977483443708609, 0.976158940397351, 0.974834437086093, 0.973509933774834, 0.972185430463576, 0.972185430463576, 0.972185430463576, 1, 0.988636363636364, 0.982954545454545, 0.977272727272727, 0.977272727272727, 0.971590909090909, 0.971590909090909, 0.971590909090909, 0.971590909090909, 0.965909090909091, 1, 1, 0.99288256227758, 0.99288256227758, 0.99288256227758, 0.98932384341637, 0.98576512455516, 0.98576512455516, 0.98576512455516, 0.98576512455516)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -140L))

gg <- df_all %>%
  ggplot(aes(label = definition, size = 100* frequency), group = age) +
  geom_text_wordcloud() +
  theme_classic()
gg2 <- gg +
  transition_time(age)+
  labs(title = 'Age: {frame_time} months')

animate(gg2, nframes = sort(unique(df_summary$age), duration = sort(unique(df_summary$age), fps = 1, width = 300, height = 300, end_pause = 3)
```

[image]

I want one frame per age, and the frame should last 3 seconds

Comment: Could also save the individual figures and make a gif with e.g., `ImageMagick` (https://imagemagick.org/) outside of `R`. I generally find this solution easier.

Comment: Is there no solution from R ? I want to make 2 videos and maybe more

Comment: There probably is, I generally do not find them very good, hence my comment.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. What exactly would make the plot "pretty"? What are your requirements for the number of frames?

Comment: I want one frame per age, and the frame should last 3 seconds